# Material UI: Place a space between two Typography components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I add a space in between two Typography components and align them at the bottom?

Here's my code:

```
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
      Project:
    </Typography>
    <Typography variant="body 2" color="inherit" noWrap>
      Example
    </Typography>
  </div>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/llqry78p29

Comment: You can put `&nbsp;` between typography

Comment: Is this recommended practice? What about aligning them at the bottom?

Comment: Alignment issue is because we are using different variant. `title` using different height with inline-block and `body2` using different. `<div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>` can fix you alignment issue.

Answer (score 8):

Just add a typography element with just white space:

```js
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
  <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
    Project:
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
    &nbsp;
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit" noWrap>
    Example
  </Typography>
</div>
```

Comment: You need only 2 <Typography> and &nbsp;

Answer (score 6):

The question is a bit old but I was facing the same issue so I'll post my fix. I used the flex property:

```
align-items: baseline;
```

So the code would be like this:

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "baseline" }}>
   ...
</div>
```

And the result would look like this:
[image]

The solution mentioned in the comments `align-items: flex-end` was not giving me the expected outcome, the text `Example` is a bit too far away down:

[image]

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2od20

Comment: or we can just wrap first typography in the `<Box mr={1} display="inline"></Box>`. The value depends on your settings of course, and seems it is not a real space symbol.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with MUI, its recommended to use < Box> instead of div. Also you can use sx={{}} prop for styling instead of style={{}}.

Back to your question, you can:

1. Add left margin (ml) and alignItems to horizontaly center everything

```
  <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems:"center" }}>
    <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
      Project:
    </Typography>
    <Typography variant="body 2" ml="2rem" color="inherit" noWrap>
      Example
    </Typography>
  </Box>
```

2. Add gap and alignItems to horizontaly center everything

```
     <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems:"center", gap: "2rem" }}>
        <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
          Project:
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body 2" color="inherit" noWrap>
          Example
        </Typography>
      </Box>
```